# Meta.StackOverflow.com duplicate chat link on top nav

Tags: bug, status-completed

I'm not sure if this is only on my PC but I see a duplicate chat link on my top navigation menu; I think this is a possible bug.

Does this happen to other users too? Or maybe this had a purpose I might have overlooked. Can anyone please explain?

*see screenshot here:*

[image: duplicate chat link on menu]

Comment: Yup, me too Chrome 26.0.1410.64 m

Comment: I think the fastest reproduced ever.

Comment: We _really_ want you to chat, guys.

Comment: I moved my eyes about 4cm higher @hims056 :-).

Comment: Who broke it???

Comment: @Oded cooked us another delicious bug!

Comment: @bluefeet: Shog, [apparently](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/).

Comment: @Matt nope, Jeff for me. :-P

Comment: noooo, I was about to ask this to get free meta rep :P

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Now you see it, now you don't.

And [Sha Wiz Dow Ard](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/152859/sha-wiz-dow-ard) got it right - it was my mess. Cleaning up some code then reverting but not reverting everything...

Yay for Meta!

Comment: No surprise you liked the chef hat!

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Mmmm bugs :)

Comment: Now I know how to really get rep quickly on meta. New recipe - 1. make bug. 2. fix bug. 3. Profit!

Comment: Won't it be easier to `Update [Users] Set [ReputationScore]=2147483647 Where SiteId=2 And UserId=140505`? :D

Comment: @Oded - Just tweet before making a bug.

Comment: @hims056 - Tweet? What is this tweet you speak of?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Naw. Don't want it to roll-over.

Comment: @Oded guess he means [this](https://twitter.com/StackExchange) but it would ruin all the fun! :)