# Missing: "Meta/Chat/FAQ" from top navigation. Reward offered

Tags: bug, status-completed, top-bar

The "meta" link (and FAQ and chat links) has disappeared from the top navigation bar of <s>Stack Overflow</s> all sites in the network...

> [image]

I'm feeling quite lost at the moment. Additionally, I could create separate "Missing"/ "Wanted" posts for the FAQ, and Chat links as well, but I think you get the drift...

Comment: Feel lost now...

Comment: It was [murdered](http://codinghorror.typepad.com/.a/6a0120a85dcdae970b0120a86e1d35970b-pi)!

Comment: It's still at the bottom of the page, but that means pressing Ctrl-End instead of Ctrl-Home, and that just feels *weird*

Comment: This also happens at [Mathematics.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com). Only the "review" link is shown behind the username.

Comment: Let me know when you find it. I was going to chat about it but I couldn't find that link either :)

Comment: rev 2013.5.17.689: the day the meta died.

Comment: No one cares about the links to `chat` or faq`?

Comment: On the bright side if I'm wrong about [where the OT questions on meta come from](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124231/were-no-longer-accepting-message-should-not-be-hosted-on-meta) this might stop them.

Comment: [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) and [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) not available either

Comment: How about showing the meta links to, say 500+ rep users? @Flexo

Comment: @Flexo - weren't you included on the memo? We are closing down all metas. (just kidding)

Comment: Eeeeeeeeek!!!!!

Comment: @sixlettervariables "A long, long time ago, I can still remember how those those links used to make me smile" ...That's how the song goes, right?

Comment: Shog [broke it](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/)

Comment: There's a link to Meta in the footer (the "feedback" one).

Comment: To be honest, I'm not 100% sure how I found my way here. No, I'm serious. *Really!* (was just coming to say something about that!)

Comment: It's not gone on meta sites, just main.

Comment: Thank goodness I have the metas bookmarked

Comment: The link to meta link is missing on all sites I went to.

Comment: All right, what smarty is making code changes on Friday afternoon right around beer-thirty?

Comment: Reproduced on Movies.SE

Comment: @Lix - `No one cares about the links to chat or faq?`  No one reads the FAQ

Comment: @LBT until we link them to it... but now that it is missing, we can't :(

Comment: Our best people are on it - we have found the cause for the issue and are working on fixing it.

Comment: Problem solved: [FAQ]

Comment: @bluefeet Shog has an alibi, he was in ServerFault chat.

Comment: @Oded was the first SE dev to show up here, therefore it's his fault.

Comment: Is it possible to put it back with the beautiful hand made design proposed by @Matt?

Comment: @Oded: Do you always talk about yourself in the 3rd person like that? (*Our best people are on it*) ;)

Comment: @Yannis - There is more to that than I care to admit.

Comment: @Matt -  I am just monitoring. Someone else is fixing.

Comment: What ever happened to read-only Fridays?

Comment: Frankly, I'm glad the chat link is gone, maybe we won't get so many help vampires.

Comment: @LBT - A [mere 43K people](http://stackoverflow.com/badges/1306/analytical) :)

Comment: If any post deserves an **EEEK!**, it is this one.

Comment: @Lix - just because they visited it for the badge doesn't mean that read it ;)

Comment: @MDMarra for that matter, what happened to it _always_ being Friday... __in Iceland__???

Comment: Instant rep-cap.  Congratulations on all the new unicorn dollars you are receiving for this question.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Until someone closes it as too-localized and deletes it, like all the other bug questions :( (waaaaahh my beautiful rep!)

Comment: Wondering how many of you were wondering if we did just kill Meta ;)

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is the hottest question on the SE network today...

Comment: @Oded Those of us who are committed still know how to get here with that browser address thingy.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Are you telling me there are some _technical_ people who use Stack Overflow?

Comment: The SE team *thought* they could keep this from leaking to meta...

Comment: @TimStone but the team knew if they had one chance / they could break that Meta trance / and maybe we'd all do work / for a while....

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Spot the bug:

```
bool showNormalNavigation = IsMetaSite && !User.IsAnonymous;
```

Damn you, [De Morgan](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws)!

Yeah - should be:

```
bool showNormalNavigation = IsMetaSite || !User.IsAnonymous;
```

Edit:

And yeah, my fault. Thanks Kevin for fixing!

Comment: Someone must feel quite the Bool

Comment: Oded *must* be put on the [Wheel of Blame](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/)!

Comment: Maybe you forgot to read this? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2848184/or-and-operator

Comment: Didn't you break [something yesterday too](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180489/meta-stackoverflow-com-duplicate-chat-link-on-top-nav)?!?  Maybe it's time for a day off! :)

Comment: I should down vote for the error. But then karma would kick my puny little ass, so +1 instead!

Comment: +1 Now the world feels right again ;-)

Comment: This is simply a meta rep scam! 1) Introduce bool error hiding an often clicked component 2) Wait for meta to blow up 3) Post answer, saving the day 4) Go to 1)

Comment: Granted, there is photographic evidence that he writes code using only one hand...that's bound to go wrong some day....

Comment: @Bart - If that's the trouble I get into writing with one hand, imagine the trouble I would get into using two...

Comment: @FrankstonRalphingtonIII - You got me. Question is, what are you gonna do about it?

Comment: @Oded I just want in on the scam!

Comment: @FrankstonRalphingtonIII - Step 1: get hired by Stack Exchange. Step 2: Get your hands on the source code. Step 3: Checkin bugs. Step 4: Profit!

Comment: Still doesn't seem right. On [meta.so] when not logged in I don't see a link to "main". From the expression `IsMetaSite || !User.IsAnonymous` this doesn't look intentional?

Comment: @MartinSmith - Good catch. I thought it was fixed as I outlined above, but the actual commit was... different. Truly fixed now.

Answer (score 8):

The link was drunk, it seems to have wandered back home now. Next time this happens we shall stage an intervention:

[image]

Comment: -1 18 seconds in? Tough crowd, today.

Comment: Perhaps people think the link was only buzzed, and not drunk?

Comment: Strange thing is: I'm already rep-capped. I can't earn more meta reps from this anyway :P

Comment: @Manishearth: "Oh, in *that* case..."

Comment: -1 not enough jQuery

Comment: @Lix: ah, now THAT'S a downvote reason I can understand :P

Comment: -1 the eyes are not freehand