# Too many review audits

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

I just had 8 review audits in a row without an actual review in the first post review queue on Stack Overflow. Same thing happens in the Late Answers queue and the Low Quality Posts queue. Is this supposed to happen?

Comment: I just had the same thing in Close Reviews. I failed a test (which in itself was a poor test, and I went ahead and [cast a close vote anyway](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16482662/android-overlapping-text-on-adapter) - it contained no code, so NARQ would have been quite fair, but it turns out to be a dup anyway) and now I am stuck in a permanent loop of reviews. Probably a good solution to Stack Overflow addiction `;)`.

Comment: I've fallen into the loop in "Late answers". I have not failed an audit recently.

Comment: The same happened to me! http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181418/got-20-review-audits-in-a-row

Comment: EEEK! I'm surrounded by audits!

Comment: @Rob Mods get audits? Can you get suspended?

Comment: I had 31 on SO (11 first , 20 late) and I have not failed audit for about 2 days (about 5 five succesful audits).

Comment: This is only on SO. Review is working fine on MSO and Stack Apps.

Comment: I just experienced the same issue, 5 audits in a row before I hit my 20 suggested edit limits for the day on SO.

Comment: I just had several audit reviews in a row on Low Quality Posts _and_ on Late Answers.

Comment: Same issue here. Maxed out all my queues on audits.

Comment: **QUICK!!! Everyone go review the Late Answers queue and click `flag` on every one! Easy way to get closer to the review badges!**

Comment: Guys I think it's pretty clear by now it's a bug. No need for everyone to say "me too". :)

Comment: And now, all queues are piling up, not just Close Votes (52.9k).  I've never seen any queue but Close Votes get as high as First Posts is now (40).

Comment: Bad news: this most likely is a bug. Worse news: the audits do not count towards your reviews, so you cannot click your way to a badge with these! Or is that perhaps the good news?

Comment: @rgettman Wow! Could a mod escalate this to the dev team? Like now? :(

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes they do - I maxed out my reviews on them, and they incremented my review count.

Comment: +1. Same here. The good news is that it means we can all ramp up our review totals... I don't often see enough entries in most review types to get anywhere near the 20 reviews limit, so my totals are quite low for some types. But if we keep getting a stack of test reviews, I guess we can expect SO to be giving out a whole bunch of extra Reviewer and Steward badges in the near future.

Comment: I got 5 review audits in a row, 3 passed, 1 skipped, 1 failed and immediately got banned for 2 days.

Comment: Once this is resolved, it may make sense to temporarily raise the caps so we can clear the queues quickly.

Comment: @Undo: No fair, they don't for me!

Comment: probably, [Oded decided to get a bit more meta rep](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180721/missing-meta-chat-faq-from-top-navigation-reward-offered/180724#comment548667_180724) again

Comment: @GeorgeCummins From the amount of people that discovered this in such a short time, I don't think that will be necessary.

Comment: @Undo: Wait, I just did see an increase in the counter. Hrmz. Ah, the  review counts the moment you clicked correctly, so if you watch the counter while clicking 'next' it doesn't change indeed. Duh.

Comment: It's a newbies attack on SO!

Comment: @gnat: LOL. that also happened last time.. same way. is this point bait? i dont know. haha.  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180489/meta-stackoverflow-com-duplicate-chat-link-on-top-nav

Comment: @George, I think they should do that anyway, otherwise we'll never finish the Close queue! This has been suggested here before though, and declined afaik.

Comment: Dear badge hunters, please come back in 1 hour and get 20 more reviews for free... Instantly!

Comment: Stack Exchange should let those that maxed our their limits on audits back in to help with the huge queues.

Comment: really, the queues will disappear quickly. I usually find it difficult to get 20 reviews in on most of the categories. Even if the backlog hits four figures, I'd guess it'll be cleared within a few days just with normal activity. (and if word gets out that there's easy badges on offer thanks to this, they'll get cleared down a lot quicker than that)

Comment: @Undo No more waffles for you! Maybe they will have to remove reviewed count because of this exploit.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd I agree with your comment :)

Comment: @owlstead oh well... :D

Comment: I just had my first failed audit while abusing this... oh, well. :P

Comment: @Robert you think that featuring this will decrease the dupes?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: It's worth a try.

Comment: [The queue counts are skyrocketing :O](http://i.imgur.com/AJ79tnB.png)

Comment: Hey! It's fixed!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Ouch, my fault... I accidentally set a flag that made *everything* an audit. I meant to do this locally (not on prod!) and somehow didn't notice my mistake until this meta thread was brought to my attention.

I am updating our logic to make sure this flag is completely ignored on prod, so this doesn't happen again. Sorry about that.

Comment: So you do trust us a little! I was starting to think we had to run a gauntlet of 100 audits to be worthy.

Comment: Are you guys partying too much lately or just working too much during happy hour?  [Bug here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180721/missing-meta-chat-faq-from-top-navigation-reward-offered), [bug there](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180489/meta-stackoverflow-com-duplicate-chat-link-on-top-nav), bug everywhere!

Comment: Thanks Emmett, I was beginning to think a review failure had stuck me in permanent audit hell `:-p`

Comment: did you add a regression test to ensure that flag won't break in the future? :) ["Your project is big enough already..."](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/159965/31260)

Comment: You now deserve to be included in the [Wheel of Blame](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/). :)