# Got 20 review audits in a row

Tags: support, review, review-audits, late-answers

I have just entered the `Review` page, and it said that 1 `Late Answer` was available to review...

I stated reviewing, and I got **20 audits in a row**! it stopped because of the daily limit, otherwise that seemed to be throwing audits to the infinite and beyond...

And now I have done the same with `Low Quality Posts` and the same happened... other 20 audits!

Is this kind of a bug that happens from time to time?

Comment: Not seen it before, but yeah, expect it's a bug.