# Delay before review audit for "Late Answers"

Tags: bug, status-completed, review, review-audits

The last two days (since the [flag-bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/181417/too-many-review-audits) to be exact) I noticed a delay of about **3 seconds** when [reviewing late answers](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers), but only right before an audit which makes it easy to guess.

Is there a reason for the delay? Or maybe, am I the only one who sees this effect?

Comment: I feel like I have felt this delay in all the review queues before an audit

Comment: No, not me. I see the delay just in "Late Answers".

Comment: it's a hint to pass the audit :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nice catch, this query was taking way too long, and making audits obvious to anyone paying attention.

We've deployed some optimizations to the SQL query, so hopefully this is fixed now.

Comment: Yes, seems to be fixed. Thanx!

Comment: Shoot. Now I can't spot the audits without thinking.

Comment: "making audits obvious to anyone paying attention." -- I though audits were _supposed_ to be obvious?