# Is the behavior of a user concerning audits used to decide whether they will get audits?

Tags: discussion, review, review-audits

Suppose that I fail to pass several review audits in a short time span. Will the system take that into account, in the sense that *more* of my reviews will be audits? I mean, in order to check whether my behavior is improving. And if I pass a large number of review audits in a row, will then the system send me *less* audits?

If not, would that be a good idea? It looks like.

Comment: I doubt the system is so "smart". Not sure enough, so only a comment. Might be a good idea indeed.

Comment: If you fail an audit, the rate goes up (normal is around 2 every 50 reviews)

Comment: I believe such information is disclosed on purpose.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Gradually lowering the frequency of review audits for users proven to be trustworthy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/226275/295232)

Answer (score 4):

Yes. You get audits more frequently if you fail one, and when you fail more you get review-banned. If you continue to pass the audits, you get less, but at a minimum of around 4%. You never get less audits than that threshold.

The exact mechanism is intentionally kept secret to prevent being gamed against.

Comment: I see. So, if I want to do more reviews than anybody else, whether they are audits or not, it is in by best interest to fail an audit once in a while.

Comment: Any official source for that? (i.e. not just a guess?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard *sits and waits for officials to comment*

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos No, audits are not extra reviews.  If you do 20 close vote reviews, it doesn't matter how many are audits, after you've done 20, you won't be able to review any more that day.

Comment: @Ward I know that! I was talking about doing many reviews in a review queue where it is seldom possible to do 20 reviews in a single day.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos - If a review audit happens a minimum 4% of the time, that means in the close vote review queue with a maximum of 20 reviews a day, you will at minimum see a review once a day.  I would image 0.8 (which is 4% of 20) would be rounded up.  If you fail an audit the rate increases, if you fail more then the threshold required for a review ban, you are banned for a short amount of time.  The time is doubled each time you reach the threshold.  This description is just based off what has been provided.