# Why is the search box shortened by half?

Tags: bug, status-completed, search

What's up with the `width: 50%` for [the search box](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=)?

[image: bigsearch]

Comment: Yes please increase it's width. It is even shorter than [the top search box](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fEMe7.png).

Comment: When did **this** happen?! Can swear it was fine yesterday..

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd - Yes it was fine till yesterday.

Comment: So, let us all see [who is to blame](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/show/)! ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like some CSS changes to an unrelated area in the site slipped in to the shared CSS file.

I have removed this specific rule and the search box is back to normal.

This will be deployed in the next build.

Comment: Awesome! [You are following it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180489/meta-stackoverflow-com-duplicate-chat-link-on-top-nav/180496?noredirect=1#comment-547648) :)

Comment: @hims056 - almost. In this case, step 1 wasn't me... but the other steps still seem to work ;)