# Inline tag edits showing for <10k users

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, 10k-tools, inline-tag-editor

My second bug report today. ([First](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182298/why-is-the-search-box-shortened-by-half))

I do not have 10k but I see "edit tags" links showing up as I move the cursor near the tags. Clicking them results in 404 errors.

[Who is to blame?](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/show/)*

> [image: inline tag edit]

<sup>* [Someone needs to update that wheel](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182332/inline-tag-edits-showing-for-10k-users#comment555542_182332)</sup>

Comment: [Hey, wheel of blame got it right this time](http://i.imgur.com/tYUuiIF.png).

Comment: I have reproduced this.

Comment: I can reproduce it on this very question.

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes I should have encouraged people to do what you just did.

Comment: [Here's a meta-meta-meta-screenshot of the issue](http://i.stack.imgur.com/7LArM.png).

Comment: I think at least it's 3 metas given that it's a screenshot of a topic about the metasite on the metasite. Or is that 4 because the original screenshot is on the main site?

Comment: We're on it. Thanks for the report!

Comment: mwahahahah....the invididual to blame isn't even on your wheel!