# Who broke the Badges page?

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, design

The sidebar on the [Badges page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges) is being pushed down:

[image: broken page]

Comment: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/AYPpF/82/embedded/result/) the person responsible.

Comment: @hjpotter92 [The wheel is outdated.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182332/inline-tag-edits-showing-for-10k-users#comment555542_182332)

Comment: I did. Sorry :(

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's all my fault, but I have fixed it :-)

The missing `</div>` was only an effect of a flunked Reshaper refactor ([invert if to remove nesting](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/ReSharper/Invert+'if'+to+reduce+nesting)).

This lead to the last bit of HTML inside the badge render loop to be skipped for single badges and this element was the missing `</div>`.

It will be out in the next deployment.

Comment: Does it also apply to the [bronze badges](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges?tab=tags&filter=bronze) appearing unformatted from [tag:continuous-integration]?

Comment: Yes, and ouch! that's terrible.

Answer (score 17):

Latest FireFox with firebug shows: Looks like missing `</div>` in a loop somewhere, I don't see `<div class="badge-hierarchy">` to end.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 9):

The fun part: [Mołot's finds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/187959/152515) in Firefox's 3D View!

(Each 3D surface represents a HTML element with a color-coded edge: the teal ones are divs)

[image: An ever-deepening pile of divs]