# My accepted answer was deleted, didn't match FAQs

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I answered [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17614062/send-ttl-signal-through-serial-port-in-matlab/18747241#18747241) My answer was accepted as correct, and then a moderator deleted it. I read the "Why was my question deleted?" FAQs and it didn't match any category. Any help here?

Here is the image of the deleted answer for non 10K+ users:

[image]

Comment: your answer looks fine to me ... :)

Comment: Could you provide your actual answer for non-10k users to see?  Also that's for questions, not answers.  See http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers for answers.

Comment: Agree with @NullPoiиteя here, flagged to ask for undeletion.

Comment: I am following this thread with bated breath.

Comment: [Flexo is your savior](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18747241/revisions). :) (@Thomas you can breathe again ;))

Comment: So what is the real reason for deleting in the first place then? Accidental?

Comment: @Bolu an accident is the only thing that makes sense to me there. I have no other idea why I would have deleted that. Apologies to achase90!

Comment: Ask @AndrewBarber (secretly) to delete another accepted answer and if you will get12 more upvote on meta  you will get 100rep associated bounes :D :P

Comment: @NullPoiиteя haha! Related point: I've stopped posting 'answers' to these questions about my fat-fingers, because I feel it's unfair that I get reputation out of my mistakes (or, admitting them, I guess!) and I don't think CommWiki is meant for just avoiding rep. Also related point: I really do handle flags much more carefully than something like this would suggest! *Honest!!*

Comment: You're slipping @AndrewBarber. We all make mistakes, but we _don't get caught_. Oh well, you're still new, you'll learn... ;P

Comment: @AndrewBarber it's fair, see [how others do this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180489/meta-stackoverflow-com-duplicate-chat-link-on-top-nav/180496#comment547648_180496 "'get rep quickly on meta. New recipe - 1. make bug. 2. fix bug. 3. Profit!'") :)

Comment: @gnat hahaha! :)

Comment: Thanks ya'll. I'm new here, so I'm glad I didn't just screw something up.

Comment: I don't think there's anything wrong with getting an upvote when you admin that you've made a mistake. Without an answer this question continues to remain technically unanswered, and I'd think it would be better if it would be answered when it actually is (and fixed as well).